# Unable to get applications in debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

**Background**

I am trying to install a few applications like tftpd-hpa, samba, and apache2 however i can't seem to do this. I've tried looking around on google for answers to no avail.
I have had some luck installing dnsmasq and ssh and I'm using those fine.  But when I try install other applications I get a bunch of error messages.

```
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate
```

Apache2 seems to have a slightly different issue:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:


apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.10-10+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ssl-cert but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When installing tftpd-hpa

```
E: Unable to locate package tftpd-hpa
```

**Attempted:**

I have attempted to change my mirror in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and using apt-get afterwards. This didn't work.   I am in NZ so I am using "ftp.nz.debian.org/debian" as the source.  And in addition I installed it from a CD and when I installed dnsmasq and ssh they asked me to put the cd back in. So I don't know if this is the issue.

**Potential Issue:**

So I think it has to do with my `http://ftp.nz.debian.org` mirror. I have changed my mirror to Australia which is just a few hours away and manage to get all the packages. I have also tried using all the other nz mirrors to no avail.  Guess my island is just dead.

Comment: Did `apt-get update` work as expected?

Comment: Yes and no. It worked and errored out on my ftp.nz.debian.org entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, remove the CD lines from the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then set your mirror to `httpredir.debian.org` in the same file and run `apt-get update`. Then retry the `apt-get install` command.

This will use the Debian Mirror Redirector at http://httpredir.debian.org/, that way it (should) always point you to a working mirror.

As for nz.debian not working, if you look at http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ there are two files at the top right now:

`[SND]   Archive-Update-in-Progress-mirror.aarnet.edu.au 24-Sep-2015 13:52   0
[SND]   Archive-Update-in-Progress-mirror.waia.asn.au   24-Sep-2015 16:00   6`

Which means the mirror is syncing from the West Island right now.

`ftp.nz.debian.org` is an alias for `ftp.citylink.co.nz` which would be why trying the "other NZ mirrors" woudn't have helped.

Comment: thanks man. did not know about the two archive mirrors.

Comment: Hopefully it's all working now. Feel free to post more questions or get in touch if you have further issues.